# What does "axonal features" mean?

Tags: nervous-system, neuropathy

In the results of an electromyography comes: polyneuropathy with axonal features

What does "axonal features" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Axonal features means that there is evidence to suggest damage to the axon as opposed to the myelin sheath.

Essentially axonal damage leads to a reduction of amplitude with preservation of nerve conduction velocity whereas demyelination results in a reduction of conduction velocity.

https://www.ninds.nih.gov/Disorders/Patient-Caregiver-Education/Fact-Sheets/Peripheral-Neuropathy-Fact-Sheet#3208_5

https://www.slideshare.net/ahmadshahir18/nerves-conduction-study-axonal-loss-vs-demyelination

Comment: Thanks a lot. What difference does axonal damage make in the symptoms that patient might experience? Is there chances of slow improvement of such neuropathy?